# Программа на C++ показывает 9, как простое число. Как исправить?

Tags: c++, простые-числа

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int number, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5;

    cout << "Enter the number = "; //enter the number example: 86597

    number = 86597;

    //cin >> number;



    n1 = (number / 10000) % 10;
    n2 = (number / 1000) % 10;
    n3 = (number / 100) % 10;
    n4 = (number / 10) % 10;
    n5 = number % 10;

    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n1); i++) {
        if (n1 % i != 0) {
            cout << "Single number = " << n1 << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
            cout << "Complex number = " << n1 << endl;
        break;
    }


    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n2); i++) {
        if (n2 % i != 0) {
            cout << "Single number = " << n2 << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
            cout << "Complex number = " << n2 << endl;
        break;
    }


    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n3); i++) {
        if (n3 % i != 0) {
            cout << "Single number = " << n3 << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
            cout << "Complex number = " << n3 << endl;
        break;
    }


    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n4); i++) {
        if (n4 % i != 0) {
            cout << "Single number = " << n4 << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
            cout << "Complex number = " << n4 << endl;
        break;
    }


    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n5); i++) {
        if (n5 % i != 0) {
            cout << "Single number = " << n5 << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
            cout << "Complex number = " << n5 << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Для начала посмотрите отладчиком что у вас там творится.

Comment: Да и вообще вынесите проверку в отдельную функцию. Создайте [mcve] и тогда думаю проблема сама решится. А если коротко, то цикл не должен писать на каждой итерации этот флуд... Да и цикл не нужен в такой поставке, на 2 и на 3 делитель да и все...P.S. 2,3,5,7 можно тупо ифом проверить.

Comment: "Как исправить" что и на что? О каком "простом числе" идет речь? Я в упор не вижу где и как эта программа "показывает 9, как простое число".

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите проверить на простоту **цифры** числа.

Проверяете вы их на нечетность.

```
for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n5); i++) {
    if (n5 % i != 0) { 
        cout << "Single number = " << n5 << endl;
        break;
    } ...
```

Судите сами - при `i = 2` вы получаете для любого нечетного числа `n%2` единицу, выводите свою надпись (кстати, простое число по английски - prime number, а не single, а составное - composite number), и выходите из цикла...

Вообще-то, если вы хотите проверять только **цифру**, то проще так -

```
if (n != 1 && n%2 && n%3) { // Простое
```

(Вы же помните, что ни 0, ни 1 простыми не являются?)

Comment: Перебираются все делители от 2 до корня квадратного из числа - в общем-то это тривиальный способ поиска делителя (помимо себя и 1), а вот условие подвело :)